# Why does my print function constantly print 0

Tags: python

Why does my print function constantly print the same variable if I am adding one each time?

```
def h():
    f = 0
    print(f)
    f+=1
while True:
    h()
```

Comment: You're only adding 1 to the variable in h, which gets deleted when you exit the scope of the function

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To most of us, we look at that, and wonder how you're expecting `f` to be anything other than `0` immediately after setting it to `0`.

So, trying to imagine how you expect this to work, maybe you're expecting `f = 0` to initialise `f` only once. This isn't the case, though, `f` is a local variable to this function - it's a new variable every time the function runs, and you're initialising it to `0` every time.

I suspect what you intend is something like this:

```
f = 0

def h():
    global f
    print(f)
    f += 1

while True:
    h()
```

Here, `f` is initialised once globally, and the function refers to the global `f` instead of it's own local variable. When the function modifies `f`, it is the same global `f` that the next call to the function will also refer to.

Answer (score 2):

Every time h() runs, it sets the value of f to 0.

I believe something like this is what you are trying to do, but you probably need to modify it so it doesn't keep counting forever.

```
def h():
    f = 0
    while True:
        print(f)
        f+=1
h()
```

Answer (score 1):

try this
the explanation is that you add 1 to f but you dont print in in the screan so your main program can't show you that the value have changed
every time you enter the h function it reset the value of h to 0

```
def h():
   f = 0
   print(f)
   f+=1
   print(f)
```